# CodeIgniter Dropdown menu

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, drop-down-menu

I have a view (**myView**) in which there is a form. The form action is **myController/myFunction1** which is used to validate the input variables in the form and insert it to the database by calling a model function. This works perfectly fine.

Now, I need a dropdown box inside the form, for which the values will be fetched from a table (called **business**) in the db.

This is the code I wrote in my model to fetch the values

```
    public function get_dropdown_list() {
        $this -> db -> select('business_name');
        $result = $this -> db -> get('business');
        if ($result -> num_rows() > 0) {
            foreach ($result->result_array() as $row) {
                $new_row['value'] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['business_name']));
                $row_set[] = $new_row;
            }
        }

        return $row_set;
    }
```

I'm not entirely sure if this is correct.
What I need to know is, if this is correct, what should be the code inside the controller and the view to display the result as a dropdown in the form in the **myView**.
And if this model itself is wrong, how do I get it working?

P.S. : I'm new to CodeIgniter. I have been going through S.O and various other sites to get this thing working for quite a bit of time now. This might seem to be a repeated question for which I'm really sorry, because I could not find a solution from the already available discussions dealing with the same issue. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try Model :-

```
 public function get_dropdown_list() {
    $this -> db -> select('business_name');
    $result = $this -> db -> get('business');
    if ($result -> num_rows() > 0) {
       return $result->result_array();
    }
    else {
      return false;
    } 
}
```

Controller :-
1. include model in your controller
2. call the function and send data to view.

```
    $this->load->model('model_name');
    $this->data['dropdown'] = $this->model_name->get_dropdown_list();
    $this->load->view('yourview', $this->data);
```

get value in view:-

```
print_r($dropdown) 
Loop your data and make a dropdown
<select name="dropdown">
<?php foreach($dropdown as $d) {?>
<option value="<?php echo $d;?>"><?php echo $d;?></option>
<?php }?>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me perfectly in getting the array printed in the view file. However, I still can't figure out how to loop the data and make it a drop down. :(

Comment: Why are you looping anything? Use the Codeigniter form_dropdown function. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html

Comment: I was about to come here to say I got it done using the form_dropdown function. :)
Thank you so much Rakesh and Rick. :)

Comment: I'm sorry I've got one more question. In `<option value="<?php echo $d;?>">`, how can I get the value to be **business_id**, which is another column in the **business** table?
(i.e. obviously after selecting **business_id** along with **business_name**)

Answer (score 0):

Call This function in controller for getting your records from DB

```
$data['records'] = $this->my_model->get_data();
```

In my_model.php

```
function get_data()
    {
        $query = "select * from my_tab";
        $res = $this->db->query($query);

        if ( $res->num_rows ) 
        {
            return $res->row_array();
        }
        return false;
}
```

In view.php

```
<select>
 <?for($i=0;$i<count($records);$i++)
    {
    ?>
     <option>$records[$i]->name</option>
    <?php } ?>

</select>
```